# different enumerate labels depending on surrounding environment

Tags: enumitem, ntheorem

I want to use roman enumerate labels in theorems, and alphabetic labels in lists of examples:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
TFAE:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item $\phi$
\item $\psi$
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{examples}
\begin{enumerate}[label=({\alph*})]
\item X
\item Y
\end{enumerate}
\end{examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to get this to happen automatically, so that I can just use the same enumerate environment each time, and the system somehow detects the surrounding environment and chooses the appropriate label type? Or maybe there is a variable that can be set in the definition of the theorem environment or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following hook after the definitions of `theorem` and `examples` environments:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setlist[enumerate]{label = (\roman*)}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{examples}{\setlist[enumerate]{label = (\alph*)}}
```